# How to get a simple multi-select box using Select2

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2, cdn

I would like to use the [select2](https://select2.org/) library in my html document because it has a [pillbox style select control](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox) I'd like to use.

I followed the relevant [Installation](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation#using-select2-from-a-cdn) and [Getting Started](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox) sections from the docs. I also loaded JQuery using a [CDN link](https://jquery.com/download/#other-cdns) but as you can see below I'm getting an error:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js">             </script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing the lib `select2` before jquery causes the problem (that's because `select2` needs `jquery` to work properly ),

move the `jquery` script on top of the select2 script then it works correctly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
```

```css
.js-example-basic-multiple {
  width:250px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    
    
  </head>
  <body>
        <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
    
  </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js">             </script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should import jquery script first, then you can use select2.min.js.

```
<html>
  <head>
<linkhref="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select
      class="js-example-basic-multiple"
      name="states[]"
      multiple="multiple"
    >
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
    });
  </script>
</html>
```